# Python - Correct Method of Parsing

Tags: python, parsing

I'm currently working on a script that'll be working with Youtubes API. I'm still learning how to correctly parse using Python, but am a little lost on what method to take for something like this.

I have this string:

```
[{'term': u'Video Blogging', 'scheme': None, 'label': None}, {'term': u'blogging', 'scheme': None, 'label': None}, {'term': u'stuff', 'scheme': None, 'label': None}, {'term': u'Videos', 'scheme': None, 'label': None}]
```

I need to take that, and turn it in to this:

```
Video Blogging, blogging, stuff, Videos
```

What would be the best approach to solve this? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how you can get all of the 'term' values out of your list of dictionaries?

Comment: Yes. If possible at all.

Comment: Its always possible. Someone just posted the answer as I was about to :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> l = [{'term': u'Video Blogging', 'scheme': None, 'label': None}, {'term': u'blogging', 'scheme': None, 'label': None}, {'term': u'stuff', 'scheme': None, 'label': None}, {'term': u'Videos', 'scheme': None, 'label': None}]
>>> [a.get('term') for a in l]
[u'Video Blogging', u'blogging', u'stuff', u'Videos']
```

and if you want to get the items as a comma-delimited string, use:

```
>>> ', '.join(a.get('term') for a in l)
u'Video Blogging, blogging, stuff, Videos'
```

I used `a.get('term')` instead of `a['term']` to  avoid a `KeyError` for items without a `term` key.

Comment: Perfect! I could never get dictionaries right. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
>>> l = [{'term': u'Video Blogging', 'scheme': None, 'label': None}, {'term': u'blogging', 'scheme': None, 'label': None}, {'term': u'stuff', 'scheme': None, 'label': None}, {'term': u'Videos', 'scheme': None, 'label': None}]
>>> ', '.join([d['term'] for d in l])
u'Video Blogging, blogging, stuff, Videos'
```

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case, you can use a list comprehension:

```
    list_of_stuff = [
            {'term': u'Video Blogging', 'scheme': None, 'label': None}, 
            {'term': u'blogging', 'scheme': None, 'label': None}, 
            {'term': u'stuff', 'scheme': None, 'label': None}, 
            {'term': u'Videos', 'scheme': None, 'label': None}
            ]     

    parsed_string = ', '.join([d['term'] for d in list_of_stuff])
```

Comment: I would pass the join() call a generator, not a list comprehension. Not sure what the micro-optimizing weenies will say, but the disassembly is only half the length.